# NullPointerException Spring Bean

Tags: java, spring-mvc

IntellijIdea [находит](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9VJpn.png) мой бин. Но когда я запускаю приложение, вылезает исключение при попытке подключить вебсокет. Почему-то мой бин не находит.
Выкладываю ключевые куски кода.

```
@Service
@ServerEndpoint("/WebsocketHome/actions")
public class WebSocketServer {
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(WebSocketServer.class);

@Autowired
private SessionHandler sessionHandler; // <-- img is from here

@OnOpen
public void onOpen(Session session) {
    LOG.error("Trying to open session");
    LOG.error(sessionHandler.test()); // <-- exception is here
}
...
```

Бин:

```
@Component
public class SessionHandler {
private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(SessionHandler.class);

private static Set<Session> sessions = Collections.synchronizedSet(new HashSet<Session>());

public void addSession(Session session) {
    LOG.error("sessionId = " + session.getId());
    sessions.add(session);
}

public void removeSession(Session session) {
    LOG.error("Closed sessionId = " + session.getId());
    sessions.remove(session);
}

public String test() {
    return "Test is ok";
}
```

XML config:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 

    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath:application.properties" system-properties-mode="ENVIRONMENT"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.exale.hms.repository"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.exale.hms.utils"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.exale.hms.websocket"/>
    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
```

Stacktrace ошибки:

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException

  com.exale.hms.websocket.WebSocketServer.onOpen(WebSocketServer.java:33)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointBase.doOnOpen(PojoEndpointBase.java:65)
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.pojo.PojoEndpointServer.onOpen(PojoEndpointServer.java:64)
  org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsHttpUpgradeHandler.init(WsHttpUpgradeHandler.java:133)
  org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:827)
  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1419)
  org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:44)
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
  java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Оба класса лежат в одном пакете.

Пожалуйста, помогите разобраться. Второй день копаюсь с этой проблемой.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я понимаю из [этого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29306854/serverendpoint-and-autowired) ответа с английского СО, вам надо использовать не `@Autowired`, а `@Inject`.

Это из-за того что `@ServerEndpoint` - аннотация не спринга, а `JWA`.